# C# - calculate if a date is six months older

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate if the given specified date is at least six months old. I am doing this:

```
if(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)>date)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Is this correct?

Some people say that this approach is wrong and will not give accurate results. Is the above is correct?

Comment: this is a valid aproach by any means, provided the 'date' variable dates 6 months back from now

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I have seen some body commenting saying this doesn't work and when I worked the logis this seemed fine to me ...

Comment: And then someone with "6 months old" will mean "6 business months = 180 days"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only concerned about the date and not the time, use DateTime.Now.Date instead. Apart from that, I do not see any problems with the code you already have.

Answer (score 12):

"6 months" is not a precise amount of time. It depends on the length of the months. In particular, you may well get different results from your calculation compared with `date.AddMonths(6) < DateTime.Now`. (Consider adding 6 months from August 30th vs taking away 6 months from February 28th... You may be okay, but you need to think about this carefully.)

You need to consider a few things carefully:

- You're currently using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`; how do you want the current time of day to affect things?
- Is the "kind" of `date` UTC, unspecified or local? It makes a difference - [`DateTime` is confusing](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), unfortunately.
- How do you want to handle situations like the ones in the first paragraph?

Ultimately, if people are telling you it will not give accurate results, you should ask them for specific examples - you need to get a wealth of input data and desired results, add automated tests for them, and get them to pass. Then if anyone claims your code isn't working correctly, you should be able to challenge them to create another test case which fails, and justify their decision.